# Race condition detector in Linux on HP machine?

Tags: linux, generics, parallel-processing, detection, race-condition

My code has a race condition problem which is randomly occurred. I browsed the previous thread but they only talk about VS studio. Is there a generic way to combat these race conditions or is there any tools available for debian to detect possible race conditions?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

Tools for race detection that I am aware of:
- [Intel's Inspector XE](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inspector-xe/)
- [Google's Thread Sanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/data-race-test/wiki/ThreadSanitizer)
- [Helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html)